# IMessageFilter for BackgroundWorker [Excel]

Tags: .net

I'm currently getting the following error when running the below code:
**Error:**

> **COMException was unhandled**
>  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

**Code:**

```
 Sub DisplayInfo()
      txtSample1.Text = worksheet.Cells(((CurrentPage * 8) + 1), 3).Value
```

I suspect that this is a result of this background worker:

```
Private Sub bwSaveAndLoad_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwSaveAndLoad.DoWork
     Try
          workbook.Save()
     Catch
     End Try
End Sub
```

Here's the WorkCompleted for the DoWork:

```
Private Sub bwSaveAndLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwSaveAndLoad.RunWorkerCompleted
    Call DisplayInfo()
```

After a long and tedious conversation with Google, I was informed that I need to implement an IMessageFilter error handler. I took a look at the documentation for it, and I still have no idea how to do this. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is a lot of copy/paste code around that uses CoRegisterMessageFilter().   Why you don't want to use it is not clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks Hans! I wasn't aware that I should be looking for CoRegisterMessageFilter. This whole time I was googleing specficially with IMessageFilter. Thank you!

Comment: I figured that was the magic keyword :)

Comment: I am sadly unable to mark your comment as answer, and I can't mark mine as the answer for another two days. Would you mind writing up something small like "Google CoRegisterMessage Filter" or something so that I can mark that as the answer? Your comment was the necessary clue that I needed, so I'd like to give you some kind of credit at least.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great example here. I wasn't aware that I was looking for CoRegisterMessageFilter. This whole time I was only Googling IMessageFilter, but this works beautifully!:

http://dl2.plm.automation.siemens.com/solidedge/api/sesdk_web/OleMessageFilterUsage.html